# Injecting variables to the JavaFX thread

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to learn JavaFX and I'm having some trouble understanding how the JavaFX thread can interact with the rest of my application. I'm using JavaFX for the interface window but I have some other stuff running in the main thread.

I load my FXML from a file I've created with the Scene Builder and I've attached the `open` method to a `MenuItem` in Scene Builder.

I've tried having an instance variable in the Editor class and populating it in the constructor as well as the start method but it's always `null` in the `open` method. As far as I understand this is because the `open` method is called from the JavaFX thread. What is the best practice to solve this problem? This goes the other way to, what if I want to access a component if the JavaFX thread in my main thread?

```
public class Editor extends Application {
    private Stage stage;
    private FileChooser fileChooser;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        this.stage = stage;
        stage.setTitle("Editx");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(
            FXMLLoader.load(this.getClass().getResource("./Editor.fxml")),
            1280,
            800));
        stage.show();

        this.fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        this.fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(
            new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("OBJ", "*.obj"));
        this.fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(
            new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("All Files", "*.*"));
    }

    @FXML
    private void open() {
        // Both this.fileChooser and this.stage is null here for example
        File file = this.fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this.stage);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't sound like a threading issue. It's unusual to have your `Application` subclass (with the `start(...)` method) also be your controller. Can you show the code that generated the null pointer exception?

Comment: I've updated the post with something I tried that caused a `NullPointerException`. I will also try separating my `Application` subclass and my controller.

Comment: I managed to solve this specific problem by separating the `Application` subclass and the controller, which allowed me to instantiate a `FileChooser` and using it in the `open` method. But I'm still confused as to how I can inject variables from my main thread into the JavaFX thread (preferably into the controller) and vice versa.

Comment: I don't really know what "inject variables from [a thread]" means, unless you are just trying to pass parameters to your controller. In that case, this is a duplicate of [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml)